# Lazarus link failed on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon

Tags: linux, lazarus, freepascal, linux-mint

I am new to Linux Mint, Lazarus and fpc.

I installed Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon and Lazarus v1.8.0, found it needed fpc and fpc-src, then installed fpc 3.0.4 and fpc-src 3.0.4, launched Lazarus without problem, then tried to run a simplest application in which there is only a blank form. It failed with a lot of "cannot find -l" error, fixed a few with "sudo apt-get install xxx" commands, but ther are still 4 of them:
    gdk_pixbuf-2.0, gtk-x11-2.0, pango-1.0 and atk-1.0

where can I find these libraries?

Comment: Downloadable Lazarus packages for Linux usually include fpc and handles all the settings for them to work together, but maybe you got yours from a source that does not.  On Ubuntu it is as simple as `apt-get lazarus`.  Maybe try again with a clean install from another source?

Comment: Try to install the corresponding -dev or -devel packages

Comment: If you installed Linux Mint 18.3 from the standard ISO, simply install Lazarus 1.8 correctly and it works like a charm. Now you probably need to purge your system from the currently installed FPC/Lazarus packages. See [here](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2017/12/26/installing-lazarus-1-8-on-linux-mint-18-3/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299758/lazarus-ide-not-correctly-installable-from-repository-in-mint-18-x)

Comment: I purged fpc, fpc-src and lazarus, then I reinstall them with: apt-get install fpc fpc-source lazarus, but the lazarus now is version v1.6+dfsg-1, and it has a bug, in design, the current form is always resized to its initial size and location when clicking a component from the component plate.

Comment: Well if you insist on doing things wrong, no wonder that the result is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me:

```
1. Installed Synaptic package management tool
2. Used Synaptic to remove all fpc, fpc-source, fpc-src and Lazarus related packages(fp-xxx, lcl, etc.), used Complete Removal
3. Manually delete /usr/lib/fpc folder
4. Reinstall fpc, fpc-src and Lazarus in order
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Lazarus and Linux Mint 18.3 just this week actually!

The solution I found was to go through the software manager, search for "pascal" and uninstall any Lazarus and FPC* related packages.

*You could of course use apt from the shell or Synaptic as Bochen has already suggested but the Software Manager is what I used.*

Then go to http://www.lazarus-ide.org and download the Debian DEB files.

The current version is at 1.8.0 and I installed them in the following order:

1. fpc_3.0.4-2_amd64.deb
2. fpc-src_3.0.4-2_amd64.deb
3. lazarus-project_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb

Hopefully, now, it should all work beautifully. That fixed the problems for me and is a newer version than what's currently available in the mint repositories.